# R - Shiny | Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Tags: r, list, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to write a Shiny app and need to first manipulate my data before I begin visualizing it.  I have three inputs to manipulate the data.
1. Channel
2. Exclude a word
3. Find all comments with this word in it

I am able to accomplish the first two but when it comes to making using the grep() function to find all rows that contain a certain word I am running into the following error
"Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'"

Anyone have an idea of how to handle this?  Or what exactly is causing it?  I think it is the grep() function that is using a list to tell me what rows contain the word.  But I am not sure of a work around and have spend to much time on this as is

Please find my two snippets of code below;

## UI.r

```
fluidPage(

titlePanel("Groupon Word Cloud"),

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(    inputId   = "selection", 
                  label     = "Choose a Supply Channel",
                  choices   = c('All',
                              'G1',
                              'Getaways',
                              'Goods',
                              'Live',
                              'National',
                              'N/A',
                              'MM'),        
                  selected  = 'All'),
  hr(),
  textInput(      inputId   = "exclude", 
                  label     = "Exclude a word"),
  textInput(      inputId   = "drill", 
                  label     = "Drill down into a word"),
  submitButton(   text      = "Update"),
  hr(),
  dateRangeInput( inputId   = "date", 
                  label     = "Date Range",
                  start     = "2015-02-01", 
                  end       = NULL , 
                  min       = '2015-02-01',
                  max       = NULL,
                  format    = "yyyy-mm-dd", 
                  startview = 'month',
                  weekstart = 0,
                  language  = "en", 
                  separator = "to"),
  sliderInput(    inputId   = "freq",
                  label     ="Minimum Frequency:",
                  min       = 1,
                  max       = 50, 
                  value     = 15),
  sliderInput(    inputId   = "max",
                  label     = "Maximum Number of Words:",
                  min       = 1,  
                  max       = 300,  
                  value     = 100)),

# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
  tableOutput('table')
)
```

)
)

## server.r

```
    library(shiny)
    source('data/lappend.r')

    #Load and manipulate data on App opening
    survey_data   <- read.delim(file = "data/Survey_Monkey_3_1_2015.txt"
                            , header = TRUE
                            , sep = "|"
                            , quote = ""
                            , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    survey_data <- subset(survey_data, survey_data$Misc_Text_Feedback != '?')
    survey_data <- survey_data[,c(2,6)]

    stopWords     <- read.csv  (file = 'data/stop_words.csv')
    stopWords     <- as.character(stopWords[,2])

  shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
    #Data subset based on Supply Channel Selection 
    data <- reactive({
      if (input$selection == 'All') { 
        if(input$drill==""){
          survey_data
        } else {
          drill <- survey_data
          drill <- grep(input$drill, drill$Misc_Text_Feedback, value = TRUE)
        }  
      } else { 
        if(input$drill==""){
          subset(survey_data, survey_data$Supply_Channel == input$selection )
        } else {
          drill <- subset(survey_data, survey_data$Supply_Channel == input$selection)
          drill <- grep(input$drill, drill$Misc_Text_Feedback)
        }  
      }  
    })
    stops <- reactive({
      stopWords <- lappend(stopWords, input$exclude)
      return(stopWords)
    })
    #Table
    output$table <- renderText({
      data <- data()
      head(data, n = 300)
    })
  })
```

Any help you can give or comments on my current code is greatly appreciated.  I also have sourced a function I used to append words to a list which is listed below

## Lappend

```
lappend <- function(lst, obj) {
  lst[[length(lst)+1]] <- obj
  return(lst)
}
```

## Data Head

The head for my data looks like below

1. KEY.......SUPPLYCHANNEL......MISCTEXTFEEDBACK
2. 1234......Goods..............'My experience was great'
3. 1235......N/A..................'My experience was terrible'
4. 1236......National...........'I ordered this item'
5. 1237......Goods..............'I got a refund'

Apologies for the poor formatting above.

Comment: Could you please try to narrow this down to a reproducible example? (for instance, removing some of the extra features, and providing a smaller or `dput`ed version of your input files, while ensuring the problem remains), Without knowing the contents of `survey_data`, and without knowing what line caused the problem, this will be very difficult to solve.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I have added an example of what my data looks like.  I hope that is able to help.  Please let me know if there is more context that I can give.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Also I am not sure which line the error occured as it will not tell me... this is the only feedback that I get.... Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4878
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Answer (score 16):

In my experience the error `argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'` comes from passing a list to a render...() command. My guess is that you're passing a list to the `output$table <- renderText({` at the bottom of server.r.

In addition, all the examples I've seen of `renderText()` just render a single line of text. If you want to render multiple lines, try `renderUI()`, which can also handle some types of lists, such as Shiny's own `tagList()`.

Answer (score 13):

Just for register (Maybe useful for someone). I had the same problem, for me the solution was to change `renderText` to `renderPrint`.

But in my case I was trying to make a summary of a `lm()`.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly this error today.

Solution: there was a `})` missing at the end of an output$something statement.

It didn't show up as an error when compiling, so it was hard to spot.

Answer (score 4):

The only problem is that you use `renderText()` but you have multiple lines of output.
You can fix this using `renderUI()` instead

Answer (score 3):

This error gets thrown when you create a `renderText` in your server and you fill it with some **html** **tags** for instance (ex: `h3(...)`), instead of a single line of standard text.

Remove the tag and the error might disapear.