# How to interpret error in write(mydata, "mydata.csv")? "List" cannot be handled by "cat"?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, export

Seems someone ran into a similar problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041449/r-shiny-error-in-catlist-file-sep-fill-labels-append-argument). However, Jacob's question (from two years ago) still is unanswered. And also, the context there is a little different from mine:

So I was trying to export my dataframe to a .csv file which usually works just fine. This time, however, I ran into the following error message:

```
write(mydata, "mydata.csv")

#error message:
Error in cat(x, file = file, sep = c(rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1), "\n"), : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Now I won't copy and paste what `head(mydata)` returns, because my dataframe is relatively big. There seems to be nothing wrong with the data and variables, as I can work with with them normally. The only thing really is that I cannot export them to a .csv file (or any other format).

Comment: Do you mean `write.csv(mydata...`?

Comment: Sure. That's what I meant. Problem solved. Thank you! #stupidmistakes ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chi Pak's comment above is right. To address your problem of saving the data frame to a csv, use `write.csv` instead of `write`.

To address your *question*, the error message arose because `write` is a totally different breed of animal from `write.csv`. If you read the help file `?write`, it is described as a wrapper for the concatenate function `cat`, which expects the data to be written out in the form of an atomic vector (or something resulting from `names()`).

A dataframe's type is `list`, which you can verify with `typeof(mydata)`. This is not an atomic vector & cause `write` to return the error you experienced.

Comment: Oh such a stupid mistake. Of course it's `write.csv()`. Thanks for both of your comments. Maybe I shouldn't work until late at night and expect any results. ;)